# Load ~ 400 (Bad Request). XmlHttpRequest works on local, but not on server-side

Tags: javascript, jquery, xmlhttprequest, activexobject, readystate

I am working on async load (using XMLHttpRequest .readystate & .responseText) of product table contents on pagination or filter changing. Funtions I wrote work perfectly but on local only. On apache/ngnix  server-side it returns bad request. Please help.

```
function loadContent(link) {

    var http = createRequestObject();
    if( http ) {

        http.open('load', link);
        http.onreadystatechange = function () {

            if(http.readyState == 4) {

                var div = document.createElement('div');
                div.innerHTML = http.responseText;
                var all = div.getElementsByTagName('div');

                for (var i = 0, len = all.length; i < len; i++) {

                   if (all[i] && all[i].getAttribute('id') == 'to-ajax') {

                      var deep = all[i].getElementsByClassName('product-layout col-lg-4');
                      $('.load').before(deep);

                   }
                }
            }
        }

        http.send(null);

    } else {

        document.location = link;

    }
}

function createRequestObject() {
    try { return new XMLHttpRequest() }
    catch(e) {
        try { return new ActiveXObject('Msxml2.XMLHTTP') }
        catch(e) {

            try { return new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') }
            catch(e) { return null; }
        }
    }
}
```

Error warning refers to this line of code `~ } http.send(null);`

It seems that problem is on `.onreadystatechange` function, but have no idea how to test it to define what an exact issue is.

Comment: I've tried to rewrite funtion to get rid of responseText (merely changed responseText to responseXML) as it seemed to be a potential reason of error. Didn't help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first argument to `open` needs to be a string containing an HTTP request method. `"load"` is not an HTTP request method. Examples include `"GET"` and `"POST"`. The invalid HTTP is likely causing your server to respond with the Bad Request error.

Comment: Solved it a moment before ur answer - and this is 100% right one! Thanks a lot mate! Would upvote u but have too low reputation, just signed up, sorry.